# Google Pay with Moneris in Angular

Tags: angular, google-pay

I am trying to implement Google Pay with Moneris Gateway. I am using Google-Pay-button-Angular but how can I connect Moneris with this? There is a tutorial in [this link](https://developer.moneris.com/en/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Google%20Pay/On%20The%20Web) but I don't know where to write script code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`@google-pay/button-angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-angular), then you should specify [Moneris gateway properties](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#gateway) in `tokenizationSpecification`:

Example:

```js
tokenizationSpecification: {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    gateway: 'moneris',
    gatewayMerchantId: '<moneris merchant id>'
  }
}
```

More complete example:

```html
<google-pay-button
  environment="TEST"
  buttonType="buy"
  buttonColor="black"
  [paymentRequest]="{
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [
      {
        type: 'CARD',
        parameters: {
          allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
          allowedCardNetworks: ['AMEX', 'VISA', 'MASTERCARD']
        },
        tokenizationSpecification: {
          type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
          parameters: {
            gateway: 'moneris',
            gatewayMerchantId: '<moneris merchant id>'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    merchantInfo: {
      merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
      merchantName: 'Demo Merchant'
    },
    transactionInfo: {
      totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
      totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
      totalPrice: '100.00',
      currencyCode: 'USD',
      countryCode: 'US'
    }
  }"
  (loadpaymentdata)="onLoadPaymentData($event)"
></google-pay-button>
```

```js
// handle the event
onLoadPaymentData(event) {
  // call your backend server to process the payment including details from event.detail
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. There is no need of a function MonerisGooglePay in link above?

Comment: These are different integrations. If you're using the Moneris APIs (i.e. `https://esqa.moneris.com/googlepay/googlepay-api.js`), then you should refer to their documentation. The answer above is for `@google-pay/button-angular`.

Comment: I am following this (https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Google%20Pay/On%20The%20Web) documentation. Is it correct to implement on Angular? If yes, where to add step 2,3 and 4?

Comment: If you're following the Moneris guide, then you shouldn't be using the Angular component as I think it is responsible for creating the button for you. Steps 2 and 3 would go into your page's HTML. Step 4 would go into either your JS file or in a `script` tag.

Comment: If I use Angular component, then I don't need to add moneris script and web-merchant-key?

Comment: That's correct. You will need to your Moneris `gatewayMerchantId` though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am facing this error while transaction with fake card credentials "Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]".

Comment: I think there's a bug with test cards details and `shippingAddressRequired`. Can you confirm that you are using `shippingAddressRequired: true`, and if so, try again without it.

Comment: No. I am not using shippingAddressRequired

Comment: Do you know what i can do to solve this error?

Comment: The you have the code available somewhere to reproduce? JSFiddle or otherwise?

Comment: Thanks for help. I figured it out